# Text elipsis overflowing

Tags: reactjs, css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-ios

I'm having a bit of trouble getting what i though to be an easy layout to achieve in react-native.

Basically i need two views, on a row, with their parent having `justifyContent: 'space-between'`.

On the first view there are two text components and one of them has to have an ellipsis when it grows.

What i expected:

[image]

What i instead get is overflowing of that text component:

[image]

```
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', flex: 1 }}>

      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text>AVATAR</Text>
        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 15 }}>
          <Text numberOfLines={1}>THIS IS A LONG LONG LONG DESCRIPTION</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View>
        <Text>9,999,999,999.99</Text>
      </View>

    </View>
```

A sandbox to play around with an example:
https://snack.expo.io/HkeFQbyvf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add `flex: 1` to the inner `<View style={{ marginHorizontal: 15 }}>` it will work

Updated code sample

```
  <View style={{ marginTop: 100, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>

    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <Text>AVATAR</Text>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginHorizontal: 15 }}>
        <Text numberOfLines={1}>THIS IS A LONG LONG LONG DESCRIPTION</Text>
      </View>
    </View>

    <View>
      <Text>9,999,999,999.99</Text>
    </View>

  </View>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

And the main reason is because the inner `<View style={{ marginHorizontal: 15 }}>` is a flex *row* item, and as such *flexes* horizontally and need a width, which `flex: 1` provide.

If to use the default *column* direction, it would work w/o, e.g. like this:

```
  <View style={{ marginTop: 100, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>

    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 15 }}>
        <Text numberOfLines={1}>THIS IS A LONG LONG LONG DESCRIPTION</Text>
      </View>
    </View>

    <View>
      <Text>9,999,999,999.99</Text>
    </View>

  </View>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Care to explain why adding flex: 1 there does the trick ?

Comment: @mfreitas For _ellipsis_ to work, an element need a set width, and `flex: 1` constrain the element to only take available space, and no more, hence the _text-overflow_ kicks in. Also, Flexbox need this constrain through all parent/child level for it to work.

Comment: @mfreitas I also added an explanation to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try adding flexShrink: 1 to the style of the first inner view